# Is there any other way to click this span? Not by span content?

Tags: html, vb.net, click

I want to click the 1st span element

`<ul class="tabsList"><li><span>Prihlásenie</span></li><li><span>Registrácia</span></li></ul>`

```
For Each span As HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.Document.Body.GetElementsByTagName("span")

                If span.OuterHtml.ToString().Contains("Prihlásenie") Then

                    span.InvokeMember("click")

                    Exit For
```

This works fine. But I don´t want to click it by innertext. I guess it is quite hard to specify, because it has no attributes.

Comment: `If span.InnerHtml.Contains("Prihlásenie")` Or `InnerText`.

Comment: The selector to use would depend entirely on the rest of your HTML.  Is this always the first item of `ul.tabsList`? Could use `ul.tabsList > li:first-of-type`...

Comment: Yes it is, can I somehow implement it in VBnet?

Comment: I got it, I solved it by counting the element position :  `Try

                For Each span As HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("span")
                    Dim a As Integer = a + 1
                    If a = 1 Then
                        span.InvokeMember("click")`